# QueryString query with wildcard omitting result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following configuration:

Mapping:

```
  "payload": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
  },
```

Analyzer:

```
"analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        },
```

and sample data (each is a separate document):

Data 1:

```
[ABCD-1234567890]
```

Data 2 (i have issues with this one):

```
<ns0:ConversationId>ABCD-1234567890</ns0:ConversationId>
```

Data 3:

```
ConversationNumber="ABCD-1234567890"
```

Query:

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "default_field": "payload",
        "query": "*ABCD-1234567890*",
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      }
    }
  ]    } }
```

Data 2 is not returned with the query above. Why is that?
If I change query to: **"query": "*234567890*"** it is returned.

Comment: Also, run this `_search` request: `{
  "fielddata_fields": ["payload"]
}` and provide the output for those three documents.

Comment: And this to see what query_string is doing: `GET _validate/query?index=YOUR_INDEX_NAME&explain
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "payload",
            "query": "*ABCD-1234567890*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: ES version
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.0",
    "build_hash" : "8371be8d5fe5df7fb9c0516c474d77b9feddd888",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-03-29T07:54:48Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },

Comment: Andrei: regarding { "fielddata_fields": ["payload"] } it is more work because I have 24000 documents there... need to dig...
But thank you for showing direction so far!

Comment: That shouldn't be too difficult: identify the problematic document, get its ID then use an [ids query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) together with my `fielddata_fields` section.

Comment: The idea is to see if the terms you are expecting to be in the index are the ones that are actually there. The same with `_validate`: see if `query_string` is doing what you believe it is. I've tested your documents and it works for me (it returns all three matches). Tested with ES 2.3.1.

Comment: Ok, I know what is happening after I run: ```fielddata_fields```. The text "<ns0:ConversationId>ABCD-1234567890</ns0:ConversationId>" is a part of longer string without spaces and in "fields": => "payload" it is divided in to two parts:
(.....ABCD-1) and (234567890....) and that's why it is not matched.

Comment: :-) I love `fielddata_fields`

Comment: So the tokenizer didn't create a long token. It has split it into 2 tokens.

Comment: Any ideas how to change the max_let in the whitespace tokenizer? Or how to overcome that issue except remodeling.

Comment: Any option you'd take, you need to reindex.

Comment: Ehh, anyway thank you very much for help!

Comment: No worries. Glad it was that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to help of Andrei Stefan I was able to track the issue.

Finally the problem was that Data 2 was to long and tokenizer split it into 2 tokens. One token ended with "ABCD-1" and another one started with "234567890"